# Font Awesome icons 4.2.0 Minimal do not display

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to put a font awesome icons for my star rating.

I copy this below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And put it in a page(font-awesome-4.2.0.min.css) this below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.2.0.min.css">
```

This work well

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

But this do not work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.2.0.min.css">
```

How can I make this (In a webpage: font-awesome-4.2.0.min.css) to work so that my icons can display

Comment: Is the file "font-awesome-4.2.0.min.css" placed in the folder css?
Show us your folder structure.

Comment: Just a unrelated note: `min` is not a minimal version (a version with lesser features), but a minimized version that still has all features but needs less space.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the folder structure of font awesome and point to the css there. Moving around the files can cause issues because they could be using relative paths to link to their other source files. It should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I use font awesome in almost every project and have had very little issues. You can see their instructions here: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/